# strange, random Wifi connection problems with 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I frequently have problems to connect to my wifi from either my laptop and my desktop computer. Both machines run with Ubuntu 14.04.

Sometimes I am just not able to connect to the wifi and the only solution seems to be to restart the router. Neither a reboot nor restarting of the network-manager helped. I also came across a solution that suggested to do `sudo pkill -f wpa_supplicant`, of which I already thought would have solved the problem, but no, it happened again.

The problem always occurs after a fresh boot or after awakening from suspension. Once I restart the router it is usually solved (although sometimes a reboot of the machine might also be required afterwards) and the connection stays stable.
This problem does not occur on other devices, using Windows, Mac OS or Android.

Here are the logs of one connecting attempt in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Bastians WLAN'.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Bastians WLAN'
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Bastians WLAN' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Bastians WLAN' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Bastians WLAN'
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Apr 16 21:30:42 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> Marking connection 'Bastians WLAN' invalid.
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'Bastians WLAN'
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Apr 16 21:31:07 Karl2 NetworkManager[811]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
```

Comment: Have you seen and followed this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before, I would recommend installing wicd network manager, instructions for install can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD)